# Auto import Google Gmail contacts

Tags: android, import, gmail, contacts

I am using Google Could messaging for an in app group texting feature. I am newer to Android an am curious as to the proper method of allowing a user to auto import thier contacts, from gmail, upon entry of the app so they can send messages to one another.

IS anyone familiar with this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

@Eatlon, you can use a contact importer that works on mobile, like [CloudSponge.com](http://cloudsponge.com). You can use the widget version: it'll provide a list to the user select which contacts to import (Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook.com, etc), ask the user consent, show all contacts to select and then return to you all the selected contacts.